# Changing Font-Family Property of a Label via Nativescript on Android

Tags: android, fonts, properties, nativescript

I have the following code with js to change the Font-Family of a Label. The idea is to access the native API of android to change the Font-Family, but it seems not to work. Any ideas what the problem is ?

foo.xml:

```
<Label text="foo" id="blogHead" textWrap="true"
            cssClass="margin-20 verticalCenter" fontSize="24" />
```

foo.js:

```
var heading = view.getViewById(page, "blogHead");
heading.android.setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface.create("Courier New", android.graphics.Typeface.NORMAL));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Courier New` is remapped to another font.

See [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/data/fonts/fonts.xml) for a list of fonts and their aliases that are built-in. To understand the difference you  might try something like the following code (any valid font can be used in place of `sans-serif-light` here):

```
var heading = view.getViewById(page, "blogHead");
heading.android.setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface.create("sans-serif-light", android.graphics.Typeface.NORMAL));
```

Comment: Be aware that the list of built-in fonts will vary by Android release (and sometimes by device manufacturer or vendor). You can't rely on all the fonts at that link.